# Phonegap iOS InAppBrowser Zooming

Tags: ios, cordova

I've recently upgraded to Cordova 2.3.0 and have added the InAppBrowser to my application (in place of the ChildBrowser plugin). I would like the InAppBrowser to support pinch zooming, but I cannot get this to work. Does anyone know if this is currently supported, and if so, how can I enable it?

Comment: I am looking as well for this  fix. No successe so far :(

Answer (score 51, accepted):

This feature is not currently available in Phonegap/Cordova 2.3. It is due to be added (among others) in Phonegap/Cordova 2.4:

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-2071

Edit:

I can confirm that this has now been implemented in 2.4.0. Enabling the pinch zoom can be done as follows:

```
window.open(url, '_blank', 'EnableViewPortScale=yes');
```

Comment: working with Cordova 3.5 as well, and the latest version of this plugin and it works fine